# How to auto login from one site into another via PHP CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, cookies

The sites A and site B are both in Wordpress and on the same server. The PHP CURL request is originated from site A when a button is clicked. The user is already logged in site A.

Now when the button clicked, it should log the same user into site B automatically. I'm struggling to achieve this.

1) From my understanding, if the user from site A not exist in site B, they unable to login. Please correct me if I'm wrong. But it will be much better, if its possible to login into site B without having to create the user in site B database. As for now, i create the user in site B first

2) Currently, in site B I'm able to get the user ID passed in from site A and log in the user in site B on server site. What I mean by server site is, `wp_get_current_user()` returns correct user from site B. `is_user_logged_in()` returns true. But when I redirect to site B url, the user is not logged in.

3) After numerous search on Google, I understood that, the user logged in server side but not on the browser as its something to do with cookies or session? Please advise me how solve this. I'm not very clear on handling session or cookie here to auto login.

From site A, when button is clicked.

```
$url = 'http://siteB.com/loginUserMethod';
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'from-site-A',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => False,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=> $cookie,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    // CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($user),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close();

//now the user should have logged in site B
wp_redirect('http://siteB.com');
exit;
```

Site B, handle the curl request

```
public function loginUserMethod()
{
    $userDataFromSiteA = $_POST;
    $userObjectfromSiteB = get_user_by('login', $userDataFromSiteA['data']['user_login']);
    $a = wp_set_current_user($userObjectfromSiteB->data->ID);
    var_dump(is_user_logged_in($userObjectfromSiteB->data->ID));//returns true
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps: `wp_set_current_user( $user_id ); wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );`

Comment: @admcfajn, I tried wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id) but after redirect to site B the user not logged in.

Comment: Not sure, but I'm interested to find out... You'll have to save the `wp_set_auth_cookie` while still on siteA before redirecting because the auth cookie that gets set by the curl request is only being saved to the session curl started... So your browsers doesn't have the cookie to access that logged in user's session. cUrl has logged itself in, but your browser hasn't (i think).

Comment: What I mean is, maybe try passing: the value of `wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id)` back with a response to curl. Then setting that cookie before redirecting. on siteB: `$foo = wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);echo json_encode['auth_key'=>$foo]` Then back on siteA `$bar = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); setcookie('notSureWhattoName',$bar[auth_key'']);`

Comment: are site A and site B parts of a multisite ? or they have their own tables separately ?

Comment: @mmm, not multisite, they have separate db

Comment: then it's a little bit complicated. The first step is that siteB receive the session id of the connected user on siteA. That can be done with a link from siteB to siteA with the id in argument or with a AJAX call. The second step is that siteB must ask siteA server side is the session id is valid and what is the username. In order to secure this process, siteA must verify that the question come only form siteB.

Comment: @mmm, could you please give a referance link on how to pass the cookie info between this two sites?

Comment: I did'nt write about cookie.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make url(of another) with password and user id then pass that url into file_get_contents(url). no curl request needed it will give response back to you.

On other site where you have to check credentials in function.php file then validate your and throw any response.